# How to implement safe copy constructor for class that has internal placement new (with std::string)

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, stdstring, placement-new, reinterpret-cast

Here's my code:

```
struct RS_Token
{
    char id;
    char cleanup;
    unsigned char array[sizeof (std::string) > sizeof (double) ? sizeof (std::string) : sizeof (double)];

    RS_Token(int a) :
        id(a),
        cleanup(0)
    {
    }
    RS_Token(int a, const char* pstr) : // identifier or text
        id(a),
        cleanup(1)
    {
        new (array) std::basic_string<unsigned char>((unsigned char*)pstr);
    }
    RS_Token(int a, int b) : // integer
        id(a),
        cleanup(0)
    {
        new (array) int(b);
    }
    RS_Token(int a, double b) : // float (double)
        id(a),
        cleanup(0)
    {
        new (array) double(b);
    }

    ~RS_Token()
    {
        if (cleanup)
        {
            std::basic_string<unsigned char>* p = reinterpret_cast<std::basic_string<unsigned char>*>(array);

            p->~basic_string();
        }
    }
};
```

Any suggestions on how to add a copy constructor that properly handles the case where a std::string has been allocated internally, would be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with making separate `std::string` and `double` variables? The code you have is going to have [serious alignment issues](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm) among other things. And if you make them separate member variables, the compiler-generated copy constructor will do the right thing for you.

Comment: Placement-new usually takes a `void*` argument, so you can spare yourself those tedious casts.

Comment: Probably `boost::variant<string, double>` would take care of these things.

Comment: Why is `id` sometimes a `char` and sometimes an `int`?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the alignment issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that what you're doing is at all a good design, but to answer your question about placement-new: You provide the constructor arguments just like in any other `new` expression:

*Construct new string:*

```
typedef std::basic_string<unsigned char> ustring;

RS_Token(const char* pstr)
{
  void * p = static_cast<void*>(array);
  new (p) ustring(pstr, pstr + std::strlen(pstr));
}
```

*Copy-construct:*

```
RS_Token(const RS_Token & other)
{
  void * p = static_cast<void*>(array);
  new (p) ustring(*reinterpret_cast<const ustring *>(other.array));
}
```

*Assign:*

```
RS_Token & operator=(const RS_Token & other)
{
  ustring & s = *reinterpret_cast<ustring *>(array);
  s = *reinterpret_cast<const ustring *>(other.array);
  return this;
}
```

Comment: That copy constructor only works if the other contains a string, and the assignment operator assumes that _both_ are already a string.  They'll need to be quite a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: @Moo: Ah, yes, a good amount of the variant logic has to be added here. But the answer concerns handling the placement construction, so I hope the OP can integrate that into her class code.

Comment: eh, true enough.  You got all the hard parts.  The rest should be fairly obvious.